# PHP script showing columns from Query twice

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Hey I have a table (names) like `ID | FIRSTNAME | NAME`
,but when I query all columns and rows, then pack them into a HTML-table and write them to a file all columns get displayed twice.

```
$name_query = mssql_query('SELECT
*
FROM names
;');
fopen($my_file, "w");
//table tag
fwrite($my_file, '<table border="1">');
//iterate over all rows
while($row = mssql_fetch_array($name_query)) {
    //start table-row for each row
    fwrite($my_file, '<tr>');
    //iterate over all columns
    foreach($row as $entry) {
        fwrite($my_file, '<td>'.$entry.'</td>');
    }
    //end table-row
    fwrite($my_file, '</tr>');
}
//end table
fwrite($my_file, '</table>');
fclose($my_file);
```

Expected result for (1, "Karl", "Übertyp") as a HTML table of course:

```
1 | Karl | Übertyp
```

But I somehow get

```
1 | 1 | Karl | Karl | Übertyp | Übertyp
```

Why does this happen? Do I have a bug in my code or did something else mess up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your html file is corrupted:

```
fwrite($my_file, '<table border="1"');
```

Should be

```
fwrite($my_file, '<table border="1">');
```

OK, did't work with mssql for a long time. Problem is a missing parameter:

```
mssql_fetch_array($name_query,MSSQL_ASSOC)
```

If you dont provide MSSQL_ASSOC then the function returns all values as numeric AND associative array, effectivly doubling the resut ;-)

See also https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-fetch-array.php

Comment: Could you please provide the contents of one of your html files created using fwrite()?

Comment: Well just was ready with the HTML, but I think this should work. I will test it tommorrow and then accept your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Issue is foreach loop running for each value getting from while loop.
First While Loop running, before end of while foreach again running.

```
<?
$name_query = mssql_query('SELECT * FROM names;');
fopen($my_file, "w");
fwrite($my_file, '<table border="1"');
while($row = mssql_fetch_array($name_query)) 
{
  fwrite($my_file, '<tr>');
        fwrite($my_file, '<td>'.$row[0].'</td>');
        fwrite($my_file, '<td>'.$row[1].'</td>');
        fwrite($my_file, '<td>'.$row[2].'</td>');
  fwrite($my_file, '</tr>');
}
fwrite($my_file, '</table>');
fclose($my_file);
?>
```

Comment: can't test this right now. But $row is just a array with all the column-values e.g. 0 => 1; 1 => "Karl"; 2 => "Übertyp", right? So this would print out the array in each HTML-table-row, or am I missing something?

Comment: Then how `foreach($row as $entry) {
        fwrite($my_file, '<td>'.$entry.'</td>');
    }` is displaying each column values @KarlTheGreat ?

Comment: Well, $row is just a array representing a row from the DB. And with `foreach` I'm iterating over the values, at least that's how I understand it.

Comment: I updated the answer @KarlTheGreat. Please have a look. And, let me know.

Comment: Well this `fwrite($my_file, '<td>'.$row[0].'</td>');
    fwrite($my_file, '<td>'.$row[1].'</td>');
    fwrite($my_file, '<td>'.$row[2].'</td>');`

is basically what the foreach loop is doing..

Comment: No. It's not what your `foreach loop` doing. When, i removed your `foreach loop` and wrote in my way (what i wrote as my answer)., it came properly. So @KarlTheGreat Check it. I'm damn sure, its because `foreach loop.`